# Average for a previous count in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the overall average just after a count step that I have performed using the following code in MySQL that works well:

`mysql> SELECT name2, COUNT(name2) FROM refGene GROUP BY name 2;`

`name2` is a variable name of one database column which contains the name of human genes, which is normal to have repeat values (for this reason it has been performed a count (through the code indicated above) in order to discover the number of repetitions par gene exists in database), but after this I would like to obtain the overall average value for all genes, not for each one.

Example,

```
name2
COX2
COX2
BCL
BAX
BRO
BCL
```

Therefore, we have a count of 2 for COX2, 2 for BCL, 1 for BAX and 1 for BRO. All those values sum up to 6 that (having 4 different genes in the examples) gives an overall mean of 6/4=1.5

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(name2) / COUNT(DISTINCT name2)
FROM refGene ;
```

This gives the overall average.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I added a text after example in order to try to explain me better.